# In Postgresql, how can I find 3 consecutive events where only the first one occurs within a time frame?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table below with user_id, timestamp and event_id. The column "tag" denotes if this is the desirable row (tag = 1) or not (tag = 0):

```
user_id | timestamp                 | event_id | tag 

    46  | 2018-12-21 08:42:35.000   | 1        | 0
    46  | 2018-12-21 09:58:35.000   | 2        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-22 06:42:35.000   | 3        | 0
    46  | 2018-12-22 07:18:35.000   | 4        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-22 08:30:35.000   | 5        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 06:42:35.000   | 6        | 0
    46  | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000   | 7        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:51:35.000   | 8        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:26:35.000   | 9        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:37:35.000   | 10       | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 08:05:35.000   | 11       | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 08:20:35.000   | 12       | 1 
    46  | 2018-12-23 09:10:35.000   | 13       | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 09:42:35.000   | 14       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-23 10:17:35.000   | 15       | 1   
    46  | 2018-12-24 09:42:35.000   | 16       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-24 10:45:35.000   | 17       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-24 11:12:35.000   | 18       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-24 11:51:35.000   | 19       | 1
    122 | 2018-12-22 08:30:35.000   | 1        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-23 06:42:35.000   | 2        | 0
    122 | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000   | 3        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-23 07:51:35.000   | 4        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-23 07:26:35.000   | 5        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-23 07:37:35.000   | 6        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-28 06:42:35.000   | 1        | 0
    122 | 2018-12-28 06:38:35.000   | 2        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-28 07:51:35.000   | 3        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-28 07:26:35.000   | 4        | 1
    122 | 2018-12-28 08:42:35.000   | 5        | 0
    122 | 2018-12-28 09:38:35.000   | 6        | 0
    122 | 2018-12-28 10:51:35.000   | 7        | 0
    122 | 2018-12-28 11:26:35.000   | 8        | 0
```

So I would like to find:

1. The number of times the user had 3 CORRECT (tag = 1) *consecutive* events (i.e. triplets) in the same date.
2. The timestamp of the 1st event for each of those 3 consecutive events.

Ideally the returned table should look like this:

```
user_id | first_occurrence           |event_id | consecutive_events 
     46 | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000    | 7       | 2  <-- 2 consecutive triplets 
     46 | 2018-12-23 07:37:35.000    | 10      | 2  <-- this has 4 consecutive events  but I am only interested in triplets of events.
     122| 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000    | 4       | 1
     122| 2018-12-28 06:38:35.000    | 2       | 1
```

In other words the columns consecutive_events must display all the triplets for a user in each day while the columns first_occurrence & event_id should display the fist timestamp & event_id of each triplet per user_id & date.

NOTE:
The user_id 46 has a triplet of 0 (tag = 0). These triplet should be excluded.

```
    46  | 2018-12-24 09:42:35.000   | 16       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-24 10:45:35.000   | 17       | 0
    46  | 2018-12-24 11:12:35.000   | 18       | 0
```

I tried to use the `DENSE_RANK()` function but the results are far from optimal:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by user_id, date(timestamp) order by tag,date(timestamp) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

**[UPDATE]**

The example I'm referring to in the first comment of Gordon's answer is the following. For these consecutive events:

```
user_id | timestamp                 | event_id | tag 
    46  | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000   | 7        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:51:35.000   | 8        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:26:35.000   | 9        | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 07:37:35.000   | 10       | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 08:05:35.000   | 11       | 1
    46  | 2018-12-23 08:20:35.000   | 12       | 1 
    46  | 2018-12-23 09:10:35.000   | 13       | 1
```

the query returns:

```
 user_id | min(timestamp)            | min_event_id | num_consecutive 
     46  | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000   | 7            | 2
```

It should also return

```
user_id | min(timestamp)            | min_event_id | num_consecutive 
     46  | 2018-12-23 06:11:35.000   | 7            | 2
     46  | 2018-12-23 07:37:35.000   | 10           | 2
```

Do you think this is possible to fetch as well?

Comment: How is consecutive defined?  By `event_id` or `timestamp`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff By timestamp. Thanks a lot Gordon. It is the first time I came across the gaps and islands problem and I really liked your response. However it solves almost 90% of the problem. The only issue is that the min(timestamp) doesn't return the "first" timestamp of the second triplet. 
Please see my updated question for a detailed example of this case. Thank a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  The difference of row numbers seems like the best approach:

To get all the adjacent values:

```
select user_id, min(timestamp) as timestamp,
       count(*) as num_consecutive,
       min(event_id) as min_event_id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, timestamp::date order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, timestamp::date, tag order by timestamp) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, timestamp::date, tag, (seqnum - seqnum_t);
```

I you want each sequence individually, just add `where tag = 1` and `having count(*) >= 3` this query.

To convert this to your desired result set, use a subquery:

```
select user_id, min(event_id), min(timestamp),
       (sum(num_consecutive) / 3)
from (select user_id, min(timestamp) as timestamp,
             count(*) as num_consecutive,
             min(event_id) as min_event_id
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by user_id, timestamp::date order by timestamp) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by user_id, timestamp::date, tag order by timestamp) as seqnum_t
            from t
           ) t
      where tag = 1
      group by user_id, timestamp::date, tag, (seqnum - seqnum_t)
     ) t
where num_consecutive >= 3
group by user_id, timestamp::date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've already tried adding `where tag = 1 and having count(*) >= 3` in the first sub-query but it fetches wrong results. Apart from the fact that some triplets are lost; this query -instead of the 1st timestamp of the second triplet- it fetches the timestamp of the last consecutive event (which is not a triplet btw)

Answer (score 0):

The number of times the user had 3 (tag = 1 or tag = 0) consecutive events (i.e. triplets) in the same date.

The timestamp of the 1st event for each of those 3 consecutive events.

Ideally, the returned table should look like this:

```sql
with raw_data as (

  select
    user_id,
    timestamp,
    timestamp::date as date,
    event_id,
    tag, 
    lag(tag, -1) over(partition by user_id, timestamp::date order by timestamp) as next_tag,
    lag(tag, -2) over(partition by user_id, timestamp::date order by timestamp) as next_tag_1
  
  from raw_data.test

)

select
  user_id,
  date,
  min(timestamp) as first_event,
  count(distinct event_id) as number_of_times

from raw_data
where (tag = 1
  and next_tag = 1
  and next_tag_1 = 1)
group by 1,2
```